# Migrating a MongoDB on a local machine to Mongo Atlas

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have a MongoDB running on my machine locally with a few collections of data. I want to migrate it to Atlas, but the Live Migration Services are not available for the Free Tier. Is there another way to move the data I current have on my machine to Atlas?

Comment: Use `mongodump` & `mongorestore` to backup & transfer your data.. See: [Seed with `mongorestore`](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/import/mongorestore/) in the Atlas documentation.

Comment: Thank you @Stennie. I will look into this. I ended up just creating a script to read each collection of data and write it to Atlas. I need to do some post-processing on my collections eventually so that method would work in my situation. I will consider your suggestion as-well, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use mongodump and mongorestore option.

mongodump --host x.x.x.x --port 27017 --db dbname --gzip --out  /data/

mongorestore --host x.x.x.x --port 27017 --db dbname --gzip /data/

Take mongoDB dump from your machine and restore it to the atlas.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

**Dump from local machine:**

```
mongodump --host x.x.x.x  --port 27017 --db <database> --username <user> --password <password> --gzip --out "C:\\data"
```

**Restore to Atlas MongoDB:**

```
mongorestore --uri mongodb+srv://<user>:<passowrd>@<x.x.mongodb.net>/<database>  --gzip  "C:\\data"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **First export the data from the local mongodb database using the following command**

   ```
   mongoexport --db=<DATABASE_NAME> --collection=<COLLECTION_NAME> --out=<FILENAME>.json
   ```

   ex. for a database named citiesDB with collection name cities we get export the data into a json file named cities.json in your working directory of the command line:

   ```
   mongoexport --db=citiesDB --collection=cities --out=cities.json
   ```
2. **Second, import the data to the atlas using the following command**

   ```
   mongoimport --uri mongodb+srv://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<CLUSTER_HOST_NAME>/<DATABASE> --collection <COLLECTION> --type <FILETYPE> --file <FILENAME>
   ```

   ex. for importing the above example to atlas:

   ```
   mongoimport --uri mongodb+srv://admin-ayush:Pass123@cluster0.cebcs.mongodb.net/citiesDB --collection cities --type json --file cities.json
   ```

**P.S.** these two commands has to be executed in the normal command line, not in the mongo shell, you also need to install mongoDB Tools to make mongoimport run. link: [mongoDB Database tools](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools?tck=docs_databasetools)